# How to set form value while using google map with ant design Form.Item?

Tags: antd, react-google-maps

I have created a custom `<GoogleMap />` component (wrapper for react-google-map) which returns the latitude, longitude and zoomlevel on onClick event of the GoogleMap component. Now I want to wrap it up with the `ant.design` `Form.Item` component with the `form.getFieldDecorator` but can't find a way to do it?
All I could do is

```
<Form.Item label="Point a location">
   {
     form.getFieldDecorator('map', {
       valuePropName: 'onClick',
       getValueFromEvent: mapData => {
        console.log('mapData', mapData);
        return mapData;
       }
     })(
       <div>
         <GoogleMap onClick={data => { console.log('Passed data to parent', data); }} />
       </div>
     )}
</Form.Item>
```

The on click event does log into the console but doesn't set the value or call the getValueFromEvent function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? You clearly suppose to get a warning in console with such code

Answer (score 0):

You want `Form` to control your component (`GoogleMap`).

In such a case, you need a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), you should implement such a component and let `Form` to pass a reference to it.

For example with function component, you use [`forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

You should read very carefully the [`getFieldDecorator` documentation](https://ant.design/components/form/#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options)), in the code you provided, using `onClick` clearly not makes your component a controlled one, and so it overrides `Form` attempts to call `onClick` events.

In simple words: implement a controlled component and define [`options` parameters](https://ant.design/components/form/#getFieldDecorator(id,-options)-parameters) to tell `Form` how he should control your component.

In the next example, `ControlledComponent` behaves like `GoogleMaps`, and `Select` component has `value` and `onChange` attributes as defaults, such behavior allows `Form` to update its values (check logs after a click on submit)

```js
function App({ form }) {
  const { getFieldDecorator, validateFields } = form;

  const RefComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <ControlledComponent {...props} ref={ref} />
  ));

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateFields((err, values) => {
      console.log(values);
    });
  };

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('map', {
            initialValue: 'hello'
          })(<RefComponent />)}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}

export default Form.create({})(App);
```

[image: Edit Q-57679674-ControlledComponent]